# Como fazer dois Select

Tags: mysql

Quero selecionar a quantidade de like e deslike de cada post mas nao estou conseguindo o deslike, alguem pode me ajudar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
SELECT SUM(likes), SUM(deslikes), id_post FROM statusposts GROUP BY id_post;
```

Comment: nuss, como eu nao pendei nisso! WTF !! vlw mano ABÇ

Comment: Se tirou suas dúvidas feche a pergunta aceitando a minaha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Voce deve usar `COUNT(*)` quando deseja saber a quantidade de tuplas que resultam da sua query, por exemplo, se deseja saber quantas tuplas existem numa tabela X basta fazer `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X`.

O que voce quer na verdade eh saber quantos likes e quantos deslikes um post recebeu e, pelo o que eu entendi, existem duas colunas do tipo `bit`, uma like e outra deslike que te dizem se um determinado post recebeu um like ou um deslike de um determinado usuario.

Sendo assim, voce pode somar as colunas likes e deslikes ao invez de contar, para isso voce pode usar um `CASE WHEN` para poder converter o `bit` em `int` 1 ou 0 e soma-los.
Como na resposta no [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460029/2509480).

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN likes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantlikes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN deslikes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantdeslikes,
    id_post
FROM statuspost
WHERE id_grupo = 70
GROUP BY id_post
```

Comment: Porque o `CASE` dentro do `SUM()`? Os valores já são 1 e 0